# InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Single'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to get a list of Food in ASP.NET. I've created a model Menu and a model **listMenu** to get list in **Menucontroller**. I'm have the following code and I get this **error:InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Single'.**

I do not know if the problem is from the database side and if it's not reading from the table

MenuController:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{               
    var foods = from m in _context.Menu
                            select m;
    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
    {
        foods = foods.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
    }
    var foodlist = new ListMenu
    {
        Foods = await foods.ToListAsync()
    };
    
    return View(foodlist);
}
```

Menu Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
namespace Resto.Models
{
    public class Menu
    {
        [Key]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    
        public float Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ListMenu model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
    
namespace Resto.Models
{
    public class ListMenu
    {
        public List<Menu> Foods { get; set; }
        public string SearchString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Razor page markup and stack trace would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to
> type 'System.Single'.

This issue is related that the C# data type and SQL Server column data type are not matched.

The following table lists mapping between C# data type to SQL Server column data type.

[image]

According to your code, since the Menu's Price property is `float` type, if you are using the `float` type in SQL Database, it will show the "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Single'" error.

To solve this error, try to change the Menu Table Price column data type to **`real`** (In the model, using the float data type),

[image]

Or, change the Menu model Price property data type to **`Double`** (In the database, you could use the float column data type).

```
public class Menu
{
    [Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zhi Lv's answer is correct, but additionally SQL has two different levels of precision for float that convert to two different C# data types.
float defaults to 'float(53)' and matches C# 'double'.
However, SQL 'float(24)' converts to C# 'float'. So in your case you want your SQL type to be 'float(24)' (or as Zhi said, change your C# to double).